# Unable to add ArrayList with multiple arguments

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList for movies and it takes the movie `title`, `year`, `genre`,  `price` as the arguments. There are no errors with the `title`, `year`, `price`. I have 3 classes, `Movie`, `Catalogue`, and `Genre` and the code for the class `Genre` was provided to me. The error seems to occurs with the `Genre`.

I didn't change the `Genre` class, but I've tried using a string and it comes up with the error, the only time it doesn't is when I put in `null`.

I expected to be able to add to the ArrayList, but I get an error with `genre`.

Pardon my lack of understanding, it is (technically) my first year of programming.

Answer (score 7):

Your `Movie` constructor only takes one `Genre` as argument, while it should take a `List<Genre>` as argument:

```
Movie(String title, int year, Genre genre, int price){
}
```

Should be:

```
Movie(String title, int year, List<Genre> genres, int price){
}
```

Full Movie class:

```
  public class Movie
  {
      private String title;
      private int year;
      private int price;
      private List<Genre> genres;

      Movie(String title, int year, List<Genre> genres, int price){
          this.title = title;
          this.year = year;
          this.genres = genres;
          this.price = price;
      }
  }
```

Edit: If you cannot change the Movie class it means you can only pass one `Genre` and no `List`. So you'll have to choose which genre to pass:

```
public class Catalogue
{
    private Kiosk kiosk;
    private List<Movie> moviesAvailable = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    private Set<Genre> genres =  new HashSet<Genre>();

    Catalogue(Kiosk kiosk){
    }

    Catalogue(){
        Genre sciFi = new Genre("SciFi");
        Genre drama = new Genre("Drama");
        Genre crime = new Genre("Crime");
        genres.add(sciFi);
        genres.add(drama);
        genres.add(crime);
        moviesAvailable.add(new Movie("Matrix", 1999, sciFi, 3));
        moviesAvailable.add(new Movie("Titanic", 1997, drama, 4));
        moviesAvailable.add(new Movie("The Silence of the Lambs", 1991, crime, 3));
        moviesAvailable.add(new Movie("Jurassic Park", 1993, sciFi, 4));
        moviesAvailable.add(new Movie("Terminator 2", 1991, sciFi, 3));
    }
}
```

Comment: You also perhaps should use a `Set` instead of a `List` (it doesn't make sense to have a genre in that list twice).

Comment: I have to submit it online and it checks if the fields are initialised correctly, if I change the field in the Movie class it won't accept it. I'm sorry I forgot to mention that. In other words I can't change the fields.

Comment: If you cannot change the Movie class it means only one genre can be linked to it. Which means you won't be able to pass a List to it or add multiple genres to it and you'll have to choose whether you want to initialize The Matrix movie with either the SciFi, Drama or Crime genre. I would choose SciFi. I'll update my answer with an example of how it looks. I would still like to argue that the Movie class is badly designed then.

Comment: Ok I think I found a solution, but i am not sure if it is even the right way to go about it, [here](https://codeshare.io/5XXnjl) is the new code I made for catalogue.

Comment: Seems you got the hang of it, and your code will technically work. A few remarks I would make myself: first create the `Genre` types and then add them to the list, that way you prevent creating them twice. Start the genre variables with lowercase, it's pretty much the convention for Java variables. The class you uploaded needs an ending bracket. And as @AndyTurner already suggested in comments above, you might want to consider using a `Set` instead of `ArrayList`, it is a little bit cleaner as a `Set` cannot contain duplicate elements. You can find my `Catalogue` class in my original post.